# Using Piezo electric sensors for Touch input gesture profiles in C

Tags: c, hardware, signal-processing, gesture

I'm working on a project that takes touch input from Piezo-electric sensors and turns those gestures into MIDI commands that are sent to an external device. I've worked through all of the nuances of our ADC and have managed to build it out from front to back using a simple "tap" as a command. A "tap" would look something like this

[image: tap]
<sub>(source: [evolver.fm](http://evolver.fm/media/Oscilloscope/oscilloscope2.jpeg))</sub>

And here's what the tap "profile" I built looks like for detection on our DSP chip (in C)

```
/* Tap Detection Function */

short tap_detect(float *x, int len){

int threshold = 200;  //calibration
int taplen = 500;
int i,j;
float y[len];
float avg = 0.0;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){

    if(x[i] < 0)
        y[i] = x[i] * -1000;
    else
        y[i] = x[i] * 1000;

    if(y[i] >= threshold && i < len-taplen-20){

        for(j = i+taplen-20; j <= i+taplen+20; j++)
            avg += y[j];

        avg /= 41.0;
        if(avg <= 0.2*y[i])
            return 1;
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

So my question is, where would I start for writing a similar "profile" for something like a circle? or a swipe? I'm just not sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 2):

Start recording and comparing, especially watch the differences between gestures, this way you can tell them apart. Doesn't sound easy anyway.

Comment: That was not helpful. I'm asking how you would take audio information coming from your buffer (byte-by-byte or packet-by-packet) and identify specific characteristics to verify what gesture you're receiving.

Comment: Well, what i said: you would need to know the differences first. Without knowing them you can't start with anything.

Comment: +1: @Ragnagord is correct - you need to collect a corpus of signals for each gesture of interest and then do some off-line analysis to understand the key differences that can be used for identification.